# How can I prevent related records being saved with the main record in EF 5 Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a class:

```
public class VehicleMovement: IEntityWithId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmpNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime MovementDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TempMovementTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MovementTime { get; set; }
    public VehicleMovementType MovementType { get; set; }
    public int MovementTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have some CsvHelper code that maps a CSV file to a collection of these `VehicleMovement` objects. During the mapping I use lookup functions to determine the correct values for `MovementType` and `MovementTypeId`, but when I try and save a new `VehicleMovement`, with an 'old' `VehicleMovementType`, I get a duplicate key exception on the `VehicleMovementType` entity.

Comment: Please add the code where you create and save the `VehicleMovement` object. Chances are that changing the order of some lines will do the trick.

Comment: I don't create the object. The CsvHelper reads the CSV file and returns an `IEnunmerable<VehicleMovement>`. I just loop through that, calling `Add` on the `DbSet` and then after the loop, `SaveChanges` on the context.

Comment: Is this `CsvHelper` anything you can change? And can you add the primitive FK properties (like `MovementTypeId`) to your class?

Comment: I know why what I described quite clearly is happening and wish to answer the question myself. I know the answer will be helpful in a wide scope of cases.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you. I hope my answer provides some value, maybe some clarity on the question, and may help somebody. Hey, otherwise we close it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a `VehicleMovementTypeDictionary` to look up my `VehicleMovementTyoe` objects based on their descriptions in the incoming CSV file. I have made the mistake of instantiating a new DbContext in thr ctor of the dictionary, while using the original one to process translated CSV records.

I changed the code for dictionary to use the same context as my main import routine, i.e.

```
public MovementTypeDictionary(ParkPayDbContext dbContext)
{
    foreach (var movementType in dbContext.VehicleMovementTypes)
    {
        Add(movementType.Description, movementType);
    }
}
```

and later in the main code, I pass in the shared DbContect and that solves all the problems:

```
VehicleMovementReadMap.MovementTypes = new MovementTypeDictionary(_dbContext);
```

Remember, objects loaded from a different context are not tracked, and when you add them to the first context, they appear new and unattached, and ripe for insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: you don't have to set both the `MovementTypeId` and the navigation property (`MovementType`), just put the id in (if the entities structure is correctly wired).

And short of any other info from you,

similar situations can be solved with e.g.

```
context.Entry(vehicleMovement.MovementType).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

If that's what you want I guess.